# Using ActiveSupport in Ruby 1.9.2 fails

Tags: ruby-1.9, activesupport

I am requiring ActiveSupport in a Ruby script like so:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'
```

to use some_hash.with_indifferent_access.

In Ruby 1.8 that worked fine but Ruby 1.9 throws the following exception:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- active_support/core_ext/hash (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from backup.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

What is the correct way to do this in Ruby 1.9.2?

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this same issue with **ruby 1.9.2** and **activesupport 2.3.5**. Ran `gem update activesupport`, updated to **3.2.9**, and the issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

First, Ruby 1.9 includes rubygems already, so you don't need to include that.

Secondly, this works fine for me under Ruby 1.9.1 and Ruby 1.9.2 with ActiveSupport 3.0.3. Are you sure that you have the `activesupport` gem installed properly under the same Ruby environment that you are testing with? (Perhaps `ruby --version` and `gem list` might show something awry.)

Comment: I forgot to mention that this occurs when trying to execute the code in a Cron job. I now wrapped the code in "bash -l -c", which should load the whole environment and hopefully the correct gem paths... will report back if it worked.

Comment: Nope, didn't work either. $PATH shows that all necessary paths are included, but loading ActiveSupport still fails... I took the lazy route and removed the "some_hash.with_indifferent_access" and the ActiveSupport requirement for now. Any more ideas and I would be happy to try them out... :)